# Redirecting from Django App to Asp.Net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, django, redirect

I have a Django app that is a form that is supposed to be in multiple languages. Temporarily, I would like to release my app with the English form and use the other language buttons to redirect to an old ASP.Net version of the form while I work on making my form multi-lingual.

I did manage to have my form redirect to the right place when I click on my "Spanish" button, but there are missing necessary Session parameters that the ASP.NET form needs to function properly.

## From my Django app:

**HTML Template**

```
<a href="{% url 'to_spanish' %}"><button type="button" class="btn-outline-secondary">Español</button></a>
```

**views.py** (redirecting FROM this page)

```
def to_spanish(request):
    request.session["Language"] = 'Spanish'
    # request.session["RandomID"] = ''
    # request.session["email"] = ''
    # request.session["nameidentifier"] = ''
    return HttpResponseRedirect('https://lspintake.nbn.org.il/IntakeForm')
```

**urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='Auth0 homepage'),
    path('IntakeForm/1', views.personal_details_section),
    path('IntakeForm/2', views.parents_section),
    path('IntakeForm/3', views.citizenship_section),
    path('IntakeForm/4', views.idf_section),
    path('https://www.google.com', views.to_spanish, name='to_spanish'),

    ]
```

(I used 'google.com' here as a placeholder. It still redirects to the url I put in the view and I'm not really sure what to put in the urls file in that spot.)

## From the ASP.NET app (what I'm trying to redirect TO):

Lines of code are used like this in C# in this app:

```
int intLanguageId = Convert.ToInt32((string)Session["Language"]);
```

or

```
if (Session["email"] == null || Session["nameidentifier"] == null)
```

How can I get these session variable to be sent over also in to_spanish view where I redirect to that app?

Answer (score 0):

Django has several methods for storing session data, and the default one is, if you've not changed it through the django settings, is database backed session storage. In this method, Django only stores a session key in the cookies, and saves session data into the database, and there is no way of another application reading this session data.

To achieve your goal, you can try using cookie based sessions as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions , and play around with encryption mechanism so that somehow you can read these values on your other app.

Finally, for the other application to be able to read these values, it should be hosted on the same domain, or same sub-domain. In the latter case, you should configure django to write sessions for base domain.